# NodeJS not looking for an index.js file

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

my nodejs server cannot find the module unless I clarify that I'm looking for the index.js file. for example:

when I don't specify the index.js:
[image: when I don't specify the index.js:]

when I do specify the index.js (it doesn't find the index.js inside ./api/index.js)
[image]

here is my package.json:

[image]

Comment: what is nodeJs version?

Comment: nodejs version is v13.12.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using babel-node